# transforming dependent bivariate data to independent data

Tags: data-transformation, independence

Assume a bivariate  data that  has some sort of dependency between the two variables is  generated by unknown distribution, but not bivariate normal. Is it possible to remove the dependency of the two variables, i.e, is that  possible to transform the dependent bivariate data into independent bivariate data ? If so, would you please point me to a paper or book that explains how the transformation work?

Comment: See maybe https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162288/making-sense-of-independent-component-analysis

Answer (score 0):

You could try *independent component analysis*, see [Making sense of independent component analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162288/making-sense-of-independent-component-analysis).  [More information](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bindependent-component-analysis%5D+answers%3A1).